# Multiple DB queries when Eager Loading in Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, eager-loading

My issue is that every time I load this view my application sends 249 identical queries to the database. Originally I was using lazy loading and the number of queries was double.

The 249 number above represents the number of rows this query returns.

My understanding is that .Include creates a join which should eliminate this behavior?

Can anyone tell me how to eliminate this duplication of queries?

Cheers!

*The code below is pseudo code and is not intended to compile.*

**Controller:**

```
 var apples = _unitOfWork.Context.Apples
    .Include(x=> x.AppleTypes)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
    .Where(x => x.Status == (int)AppleStatusConstants.New 
          && x.IsRejected != true && x.AppleManId != null);

 return View(apples);
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Apple>

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AppleTypes.TypeSeason)
@foreach (var item in Model){
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AppleTypes.TypeSeason)
         }
```

**SQL Trace from Glimpse:**

```
    SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Type] AS [Type],  
[Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
[Extent2].[TypeSeason] AS [TypeSeason], 

FROM  [dbo].[Apples] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AppleTypes] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
WHERE (0 = [Extent1].[Status]) AND ( NOT ((1 = [Extent1].[IsRejected]) AND ([Extent1].[IsRejected] IS NOT NULL))) AND ([Extent1].[OrgUnitId] IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] DESC
```

**Glimpse Screenshot**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Multiple DB queries when Eager Loading in Entity Framework 6

You haven't told it to Eager Load the *base* query, only it's Includes.

This code:

```
var apples = _unitOfWork.Context.Apples
  .Include(x=> x.AppleTypes)
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
  .Where(x => x.Status == (int)AppleStatusConstants.New 
         && x.IsRejected != true && x.AppleManId != null);
```

Is creating an `IQueryable< T >`.  The simple solution is to add `.ToList()` at the end.

```
  .Where(x => x.Status == (int)AppleStatusConstants.New 
     && x.IsRejected != true && x.AppleManId != null)
  .ToList();
```

So in your code, this is the culprit:

```
@foreach (var item in Model){
```

That is causes EF to query for one entity at a time.

PS: The following Statements are identical (unless you've overridden object.cshtml)

```
@foreach (var item in Model){
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AppleTypes.TypeSeason)
}
```

and

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m)
```

and

```
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

Comment: Is .ToList() a more expensive operation? One of the senior programmers here encourages me not to user .ToList() whenever possible

Comment: There is no good answer.  It simply depends.  There are times when `.ToList()` is the correct solution and times when it is not.